# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'toList'

Tags: arrays, list, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to append certain columns of `Pandas Data Frames` from `CSV` files into a numpy array. I have no idea how to instantiate an empty numpy array, so I'm testing it first with a list.

```
def windows(files):
    x = []
    for my_files in files:
        with open(os.path.join("/Users", "saqibali", "PycharmProjects", "sensorLogProject", "Data", my_files),
              'rU') as my_file:
            df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['timestamp', 'time skipped', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'label']).set_index('timestamp')
            for d in sliding_window(sample_difference(my_file), 500, 250):
                df = df.append(d[['x', 'y', 'z']])
            x.append(df.values.toList())
    return x
```

I get the error in the title, and it doesn't make sense to me because `x` is a `list` and `df` is a `Data Frame`.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The method name is all lowercase: [`tolist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html).

So you need to change the offending line to:

```
x.append(df.values.tolist())
```